# How do I get the Progress bar filled up by the amount of time I hold down?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective c, how can I implement the progress bar being filled during the time I press the button?

I can not even start because I'm new.

Comment: I would recommend first of all to find an xcode example project of using UIProgressView, open it and launch.

Comment: may this help you  https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-a-progress-bar          Hope it works..!

Comment: IMHO, reading the documentation should be the start and not directly asking what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Maximum limit first, with this value your proportional UIProgressBar will be filled.

For example :

if you set maximum limit to 100 seconds, Then Every second touched will be the progress of your UIProgressBar.

```
yourProgressbar.progress = maximum/touchedSecond
```

Now to detect touch You need to implement **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** .

You can Start your counter for second touched with

```
UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
```

End your counter with event

```
UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
```

You need to implement timer along with it to increment second count.

This is easiest way.
May this guideline help you to move ahead with your code.